# I want to write ASP.NET code showing the use of FileUpload

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload

I have written a code  in which when the user clicks upload button the word  file should be saved and redirect to the 2nd page, the word file is saving in the given path, but it is not printing any output(it is showing me blank page)

1st page.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class pg_upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string fname = FileUpload1.FileName;

    if (FileUpload1.HasFiles)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Selected file uploaded";

    }
    else {
        Label1.Text += "Select a file";
        return;
    }
    int flength=FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    Int32 a = flength * 1024;
    if (flength > a)
    {
        Label1.Text += "File Out Of Range";
    }
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType != "application/msword")
    {
        Label1.Text += "Upload word files only";
    }
   FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~")+"/Myfolder/"+
FileUpload1.FileName);
    Response.Redirect("pg_viewUploads.aspx");
}
```

}

My 2nd page.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  public partial class pg_viewUploads : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string fpath=Server.MapPath("~")+"/Myfolder";
    string [] files=Directory.GetFiles(fpath);
    string[] name=new string[files.Length];
    FileInfo fi;
    int i=0;
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        fi = new FileInfo(s);
        name[i] = "/Myfolder/" + fi.Name;
        i++;

    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table>");
    i = 0;
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        for (int k = 1; k <3; k++)
        {
            if (i > files.Length-1)
            { return; }
            sb.Append("<a href="+ name[i] + ">" +name[i]+"</a>");
            i++;

        }
        sb.Append("</tr>");

    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");
    Label b = new Label();
    b.Text = sb.ToString();
    b.Visible = true;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);


}
}
```

[This pic will give you detail idea of how to code should run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yibyc.png)
Please provide solution.any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not printing any output"?

Comment: means it is showing me blank page

Comment: So assuming that the file is uploaded and that you can successfully open it, you actually don't need any help uploading the file. You need help displaying a list of file names, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you are embedding `<tr>` tags in a `<tr>` tag. This is not allowed in HTML.

The second issue I see is that you are looping over `j` and `k` for no obvious reason. Looping over the `files` array should be enough.

Comment: I have used for loop to print it in a table